# Excel Validation - IsEmpty or #CALC!?

Tags: excel, validation

I'm trying to add some validation to cell `D16` which is configured using a list.

Normally this cell will show a list of options for the user to select. However if they haven't added values to another sheet, this list will show `#CALC!`

Currently I've got:

```
Set Check = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Home").Range("D16")
If IsEmpty(Check.Value) Then
    MsgBox "Warning...."
End If
```

This works when no option is selected, but if the user hasn't added the options to the other sheet, the list offers `#CALC!` and if the user selects that the check doesn't work.

The value of the option will always be over 10 characters, so I've tried:

```
   If (Len(Check.Value) < 10) Then
       MsgBox "Warning...."
   End If
```

But that doesn't work.

Is there any way to check for a blank entry or #CALC! or check the length of whats in the cell and would that include #CALC! ?

Thanks

Comment: The Value() property returns a Variant. This might be a number, string or several other things, one of which is a special Error type. Use the `IsError()` function to test whether a value is of such a type (error 2050).

Comment: @DS_London If you can create that as an answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there any way to check for a blank entry or #CALC! or check the
> length of whats in the cell and would that include #CALC! ?

The `Value()` property of a `Range` returns a `Variant`. This is a datatype which may be a number, a string, an array, or several other types of data. If a spreadsheet cell has an error in it (displayed as #NUM!,#VALUE!,#CALC! etc) then this is a separate Error type, and can be tested using `IsError()`.

Each error has a number associated with it: for #CALC! this is 2050. If you want to check the error was specifically #CALC! you can compare the value to `CvErr(2050)`, or convert to a string representation using `CStr()`:

eg

```
Sub TestError()
    Dim v as Variant
    v = CVErr(2050)
    
    If IsError(v) Then
        Debug.Print CStr(v)
    End If
End Sub
```

which prints (in the Immediate window):

```
Error 2050
```

Comment: Thanks :) That has helped to resolve the issue.